# C# detect folder junctions in a path

Tags: c#, junction

I want to make a quick check if in a complete path a Junction point is used. I already have a function to test a folder like `IsJunction()` but maybe there is an other solution to not call `IsJunction()` on every subfolder.

So I'm looking for a function like `HasJunctionsInPath(string path)` without testing each folder of the path.

Is there something which can do this?

Edit:

Or better...

Is it possible to resolve all junctions in a path to get the real location of a file or folder? This would be even better solve my problem and I still can compare the result with the original path to implement a `bool HasJunctionsInPath(string path)` function.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the solution of Jeff Brown.

He implemented your features in a static class, that seems to just work fine.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/JunctionPointsNet.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there's no out of the box implementation in c# to handle junctions / reparse points directly.

So you have to do some interop with kernel32.dll. This is a bit tricky, but you find samples.
You'll need the CreateFile() & DeviceIoControl() calls.

Here is a good sample to start:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/ReparsePointID.aspx?display=Print

useful msdn links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232007%28PROT.13%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/7acd564f-0e9f-4295-8609-916af6675f0a

Comment: Have a look at this site too: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.DeviceIoControl it will help you to get the signatures.