# How to easy resolve/normalize local file path with Powershell 5+ (symlinks/junctions-aware)?

Tags: powershell, symlink, powershell-5.0, junction

I need Powershell 5.1 to resolve(normalize) existing local file path similar to [tcl normalize](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10078) or POSIX [`realpath`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/realpath/) similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404124/path-normalization-with-respect-to-ntfs-reparse-points-symlinks-directory-junct), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943630/c-sharp-detect-folder-junctions-in-a-path) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926127/powershell-to-resolve-junction-target-path).

Say this filename referenced by full path:

```
D:\temp\multilink\junction-to-other-dir\absolute-symlink-to-other-dir\relative-symlink-to-other-dir\junction_target_dir_contents.txt
```

should resolve to

```
D:\exp\junction_target_dir\junction_target_dir_contents.txt
```

[Resolve-Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path) and [[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are not resolving symlinks and junctions.

Traversing path up and resolving each folder using `(Get-Item $parent_path_part).Target[0]` works but looks cumbersome.

Good old [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926224/2746150) API does work.

Am I missing any modern(simple) Powershell 5+ way to accomplish this?

EDIT: THIS QUESTION IS NOT 100% DUPLICATE OF [powershell to resolve junction target path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926127/powershell-to-resolve-junction-target-path).

First of all I am looking to resolve multiple junctions and/or symlinks that may be present in the given file path.

Secondly I am looking for nice, simple and possible one-line solution given the improvements of Powershell 5 and 5.1.

That is I am looking for solution ALTERNATE to ones listed in linked questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell to resolve junction target path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926127/powershell-to-resolve-junction-target-path)

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin: I have referenced this and two other would be duplicates in my question. Still I am asking about a bit different thing - complete path resolution not just one part of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell to resolve junction target path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926127/powershell-to-resolve-junction-target-path)

Comment: Why do you think using Get-Item `target` is cumbersome? Anyway, I don't see any other related usages of FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT in powershell source code on github.

Comment: @wOxxOm: It is easy for simple cases like `c:\junction\file.txt`. It is complex for say `c:\junction1\absolute-symlink\relative-symlink\file.txt`

Comment: Indeed. Well, I see no GetFinalPathNameByHandle used in [.NET 4 source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html) as well.

Comment: Further tests have shown that ps5 get-item does not work well for complex cases. If you stack links on each other funny things happen. Say you create hardlink for symlink. Get-item here completely misses hardlink data.